How to set the field value dynamically using the physical Column annotation name from entity class
I am trying to set the the field values in entity class using the annotation column names.
Below is an example
Loans is my entity class
public class Loans{
 @Column(name = "CORR_ID")
 private String corrId;

@Column(name = "FILE_RCEIVED_MONTH")
private Date fileRcvdMonth;
}

I have a Map which have physical column names from table and its respective values , this is coming from external system.
Map<String , String > configColumnNames = new HashMap<>();
  configColumnNames.put("CORR_ID","123");
  configColumnNames.put("FILE_RCEIVED_MONTH","11");

What i am trying to do is like below
for (Field field : loan.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
  Column column = field.getAnnotation(Column.class);
    if(configColumnNames.containsKey(column.name())){
      //loan.setCorrId(configColumnNames.get(column.name()));
      // how i can find which field (setCorrId) in loan to set
    }
}

Or is there any other better way to implement this .

Basically, this is the way. You may enhance this by create at some startup time a map that holds the name as key and setter and getter Method as values to not always make a lookup through all fields.
